# mass pass-by-reference for string changing functions?

Tags: php, string, pass-by-reference

For string functions, I find myself doing this kind of thing a lot:

```
$string = trim($string);
```

I would like to easily have functions where I can pass the string by reference, so I can instead do `function($string);`.

I was thinking about writing wrappers for all the string functions I want to use, and prefix it with a special character, like so:

```
 function _trim(&$string) {
   trim($string);
 }

 function _str_replace($a, $b, &$string) {
    str_replace($a, $b, $string);
 }
```

But I wonder if there's a way that's easier than writing a wrapper for each function? (Has someone written this library already?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For functions that can take only one argument (the string) like `trim()`, `strtolower()` etc, you could do something like this maybe...?

```
function modify_str (&$str, $funcName) {
  if (function_exists($funcName)) $str = $funcName($str);
}

// So you can now do
modify_str($str, 'trim');
modify_str($str, 'strtolower');
```

...but to be perfectly honest, I cant really see the point - for one thing, you can't chain functions that take an argument by reference (i.e. you can't do `trim(strtolower($str))`)

I tend not to write `$str = trim($str);` very much, because I am probably going to use the result fairly immediately in some other operation. Instead of this:

```
$str = trim($str);
some_func($str, $someOtherVar);
```

I just do this:

```
some_func(trim($str), $someOtherVar);
```

And in the event that I need to do something like this:

```
$str = trim($str);
some_func($str, $someOtherVar);
another_func($str, $yetAnotherVar);
```

I would do this:

```
some_func($str = trim($str), $someOtherVar);
another_func($str, $yetAnotherVar);
```

...but whatever you are trying to do by doing any of the above, what you are effectively achieving is making your code less readable, and probably nothing else.

**EDIT**

After doing something completely unrelated today, I realised there is a way to chain functions and call it by reference:

```
function modify_str (&$str) {
  $args = func_get_args();
  for ($i = 1; isset($args[$i]); $i++) {
    if (function_exists($funcName = $args[$i])) $str = $funcName($str);
  }
}

// So you could do
modify_str($str,'trim','strtolower');
```

...but I still maintain this is not the way to go.

**ANOTHER EDIT**

You could pass to functions that uses multiple arguments by doing something like this (untested):

```
function modify_str (&$str) {
  $str_identifier = '$$$'; // This identifies the argument where $str should be used
  $ops = func_get_args();
  for ($i = 1; isset($args[$i]); $i++) { // Loop functions to be applied
    if (function_exists($ops[$i]['function'])) {
      $args = array();
      for ($j = 0; isset($ops[$i][$j]); $j++) { // Loop arguments for this function and build an argument list in PHP syntax
        $args[] = ($ops[$i][$j] === $str_identifier) ? '$str' : "\$ops[\$i][$j]";
      }
      // eval() it (as if you had written it as straight PHP)
      eval("\$str = {$ops[$i]['function']}(".implode(',',$args).");");
    }
  }
}

// So you can call it like this
modify_str($str,array('function'=>'str_replace','&','&amp;','$$$'),array('function'=>'explode',"\n",'$$$'));
// ..which should have the same effect as
$str = explode("\n",str_replace('&','&amp;',$str));

// As you can see, the not-by-reference way is is much shorter and more readable
```

Comment: Good points. I just get sick of typing `$string = function($string)`, which apparently I do more often than you find yourself doing.

Comment: This is a tangential question, but if you also returned the value, could you then nest (or chain) the reference functions?

Comment: I just tested it. Answer: Nope!

Comment: You can't do that because of a limitation of the Zend engine whereby the result of an expression cannot be passed by reference without first being assigned to a variable (which makes sense, if you think about it). So you *could* do `modify_str($str = modify_str($str, 'strtolower'), 'trim');` if you returned the value, but then you haven't gained anything, as this is actually *longer* than typing `$str = trim(strtolower($str));`

Comment: that's pretty cool! :) But I was also trying to think of a way where you could pass by reference the string to a string-modifying function that has multiple arguments, in various orders, like `str_replace()`. Seems like it'd be a huge kludge if you could do it at all :P

Comment: See another edit - as you can see it's getting less readable/efficient the more you try and get out of it...

Comment: This really won't be a whole lot different from some of the code snippets pasted on php.net ;)